# Laravel - Redirect Catch / Redirect Urls with an .php ending

Tags: php, url, laravel-5, routes, seo

I have an old static PHP Website, which I would like to update and rebuild it with Laravel. My Problem, all the SEO Links are already indexed with a **.php** ending.

Is there any chance to catch the URLs with a .php ending and redirect to URLs without a .php ending?

```
www.website.com/index.php -> www.website.com
www.website.com/en/products.php -> www.website.com/en/products
```

Thanks for your, help!

Comment: I think you'll have more issues rebuilding it with laravel than just .php file extension, but to solve this read about HTACCESS

Comment: Hi Sam, What do you mean by more issues?

Comment: that's if you are trying to embed your old static code into laravel, it might begin to throw lots of error

Comment: I just talked about rebuilding the URL->Structure, of course not the static code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file in the directory where your .php files are and paste this code inside the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```